# Electron: Close w X vs right click dock and quit

Tags: javascript, electron

In my Electron app, I would like to do something that is done very often in other OSX apps. That is... I would like to NOT close the app of the red X is clicked in the top right. But, if they right click the app icon in the dock, and say Quit, then I would like to quit the app. How do I do this?

I have tried using the `onbeforeunload` event from the rendererProcess, as well as the `browserWindow.on("close", fn)` event to try and prevent this. The problem is that they both file the `onbeforeunload` event. And I can't tell the different between the red X being clicked and the dock icon being right clicked and told to quit. Any help would be nice. Has anyone else done this in Electron for OSX?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this

```
if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  var forceQuit = false;
  app.on('before-quit', function() {
    forceQuit = true;
  });
  mainWindow.on('close', function(event) {
    if (!forceQuit) {
      event.preventDefault();

      /*
       * your process here
       */
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct and concise. Thanks for that. A bit of an explanation of what's going on to help clarify: app's `before-quit` event fires _before_ browser windows are closed, so if you quit from something other than closing the browser window (dock context menu, application menu, etc) `before-quit` will fire before the mainWindow's `close` event. If you close by clicking the x on the main window, the window's `close` event will fire first. http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-before-quit

Answer (score 7):

This is the only answer that worked for me:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;

let willQuitApp = false;
let window;

app.on('ready', () => {
  window = new electron.BrowserWindow();

  window.on('close', (e) => {
    if (willQuitApp) {
      /* the user tried to quit the app */
      window = null;
    } else {
      /* the user only tried to close the window */
      e.preventDefault();
      window.hide();
    }
  });

  window.loadURL('foobar'); /* load your page */
});

/* 'activate' is emitted when the user clicks the Dock icon (OS X) */
app.on('activate', () => window.show());

/* 'before-quit' is emitted when Electron receives 
 * the signal to exit and wants to start closing windows */
app.on('before-quit', () => willQuitApp = true);
```

via https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-catch-the-event-of-clicking-the-app-windows-close-button-in-electron-app/21425/8

Answer (score 0):

After much looking, I found the following solution. When you right click on the dock and select `Quit`, before that fires the `onbeforeunload` in the rendererProcess, it will first fire the `close` event on the app itself. So, in the rendererProcess you have an `onbeforeunload` listener. And you tell that to return false always. Returning false from that event will prevent the window from unloading/closing ever. Then in your mainProcess you add `app.on('close',fn)` listener. That listener can send an event to the rendererProcess telling it to allow the close. Perhaps you can set a global `allowClose = true` or something. Then in your `onbeforeunload`, you add the logic to not return true if `allowClose` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [window-all-closed](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.4/api/app/#event-39-window-all-closed-39) event of `app` in the main process. This event is typically used to quit the app on Linux and Windows but not on OS X (for an example, see Electron's [Quick Start Tutorial](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.4/tutorial/quick-start/)). On OS X you should then probably also handle the [activate](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.4/api/app/#event-39-activate-39-os-x/) event to open a new window if there is currently no window open.

Comment: You know what. Reading your reply, I have realized that my app is probably different than a lot of Electron apps. Rather than being oriented around the node app that is the electron main process, my app is oriented around the app loaded in the remote url that I wrap. Thus... if the windows all close, then the main part of my app is dead. Whereas most electron apps would still be running. So... considering that, this answer is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the electron [quick start guide](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md)

Please notice the two below solutions needs to be implemented in `main.js`, and not on the JS executed on your html page.

#### Specific window close

If you want to execute code when a specific [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) is closed:

```
mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Your code to be executed before "really" stopping the app
});
```

#### All window close

If you want execute code when ALL the windows are closed ([`app` API](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md)):

```
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this from your `main.js` file, by checking if it's a darwin platform, on `window-all-closed` event and re-create the window on `activate` event.

```
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

More info/Example: https://github.com/atom/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it and this works perfectly.

```
import { app } from "electron";
let window: any;
let forceQuit = false;

app.on("ready", () => {
    window = //YOUR BROWSER WINDOW
    window.on("close", e => {
      if (process.platform === "darwin" && forceQuit) {
        window = null;
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        app.hide();
      }
});

app.on("activate", function() {
    app.show();
});

app.on("before-quit", function(event) {
    if (!forceQuit) {
      event.preventDefault();
      forceQuit = true;
      app.quit();
    }
});
```