# Electron Browser Window Prevent Control+W closing window

Tags: angular, electron

I have an electron js app with Angular 8. If the user performs the command control+w, it automatically closes the window. I try looking through the [BrowserWindow Api](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window), however, I couldn't find a flag or handler to prevent this behavior from happening.

Comment: It would be a major usability problem if websites could prevent users from closing them. Even if it's just a key combination they block, as some users actually use those key combinations instead of their mouse. Same goes for desktop applications.

Comment: That’s a great point about usability. The usability I’m going for is similar to VSCode, in that it has tabs, and I want the user to be able to close tabs with control+w, and when it gets to the last one it closes the window.

Comment: One of the questions listed as related is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392806/how-to-preventdelay-oswindows-10-from-closing-electron-window?rq=1. Can you check if the solution listed there actually works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change or remove the default application menu which has this shortcut `Window -> Close Ctrl+W` by default

```js
Menu.setApplicationMenu(null) // remove default application menu

// or

browserWindow.setMenu(null) // just remove default menu of a specific window and not all windows
```

This should do the trick

Relevant docs:

- [Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menusetapplicationmenumenu)
- [win.setMenu(menu)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Removing the default application menu removes other useful shortcuts, so I would suggest specifically targeting Ctrl + W, which can be done using `globalShortcut`:

```
const { app, globalShortcut } = require("electron");

app.on("ready", () => {
    globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+W", () => {
        //stuff here
    });
});
```

More info on this [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut)

Comment: Other Menu and Browser methods didn't work for me (at least in loca debugging), trying this one in conjunction app.dock.hide()

BTW there's a missing ')' closing register() function.

Comment: Although overriding shortcut works, I wasn't able to prevent default behavior, ended up using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782702/970375

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it blocks this shortcut for all apps, not just your app. Also, you would still have a menu item in your app menu that says it has an accelerator "Ctrl+W". You can edit your application menu to disable and hide that menu item (while keeping the useful others) which imo is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

For whom it may concern, another solution can be:

```
app.on("ready", () => {
  app.on("browser-window-focus", () => {
    globalShortcut.registerAll(
      ["CommandOrControl+R"],
      () => {
        return;
      }
    );
  });
  app.on("browser-window-blur", () => {
    globalShortcut.unregisterAll();
  });
});
```

This way we prevent from blocking globalShortcuts in other applications.
More info about electron accelerators: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/accelerator